# Change font of WordPress theme "Zerif Lite"

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I'm having trouble changing the font on a website I built using the WordPress theme `Zerif Lite`.

The page itself is (REMOVED LINK) - I want to change the font in the "*testimonial*" section or as its displayed there: "*Teenused*".

That weird font in the bottom of every box (`a.client-name`)
I have tried so far:

1. Custom CSS plugin - it lets me only change the font size, when I set new font there, it won't change anything.
2. Changed the theme's CSS files, also no luck there.

Will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font by targeting the correct selector, which is: `.feedback-box .client-info .client-name`. The current font is called `Homemade Apple` and is declared in the main theme's CSS file ([style.css](http://elektripoisid.ee/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/style.css?ver=v1)) at line 2797:

```
.feedback-box .client-info .client-name {
    font-family: 'Homemade Apple', serif;
    color: #404040;
}
```

Simply change that to your desired font, for example:

```
.feedback-box .client-info .client-name {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add an `!important` rule to your CSS. It's either that or verify the load order from your styles.
When it comes down to a CSS style, the reason it may not be aplying is because there is another more specific selector, try adding parent selector to your rules, or it could also be that the theme's rules are loading after your rules and replacing them.

One last thing to check, when dealing with fonts: make sure your browser have access to and knows the font. If it does not finds it, it will just replace it with another one, without any warning.

Comment: Adding `!important` is bad practice and should only be used as a last resort.